# How to create administrator user in gerrit with ldap authentication?

Tags: ldap, gerrit

I am using errit Code Review 2.12 with LDAP authentication, mysql database.

```
[auth]
    type = LDAP
[ldap]
    server = ldap://server
    accountBase = ou=administrator,dc=company,dc=com
    referral = follow
    accountPattern = (uid=${username})
    accountFullName = cn
    accountEmailAddress = mail
```

and in my LDAP

```
dc=company,dc=in (3)
---> cn=admin
+--> ou=administrator (1)
| ---> cn=dev
+--> ou=people (1)
| ---> cn=test user
```

The test user can able to login, but not assigned with administrator group.
What is wrong in the configurations ?

Comment: Maybe this thread? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/3jz7wq4VqVw

Answer (score 0):

The first user connecting to an empty Gerrit instance is added to `Administrators` groups.

If this first connected user want to add other Administrator, he has to add it using Gerrit UI under `People > List Groups > Administrators > Members`

[image]

Then add the user into the group :

[image]

If you don't remember the first user connected to your instance, do that (come from there : [Details](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/3jz7wq4VqVw))

> Check in your database how many accounts you have created: stop your gerrit instance and from the review_site folder execute:  java -jar bin/gerrit.war gsql
>
> When it starts type:  select * from accounts. The one with the lowest
>   account_id (1?) should be an admin.
>
> Also check: select * from account_groups;

Comment: I am not sure this is entirely true. In my case I have got LDAP authentication and I am the first and only one to have accessed gerrit. Also I checked my user ID as suggested and it's the lowest (1). Yet, I can't do anything as I appear to be just a simple authenticated user